# Jquery dynamically generate input only validate first in Laravel 5.8

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-5.8

I have to generate dynamic inputs using jquery and validate it by using jquery validation plugin. The problem is it is just validating only first input field.

I have tried all the thing like changing validation rules, changing the version, changing the loops, etc

My Current Jquery version are as following.

jquery v3.2.1
validation v1.11.1
additional methods 1.16.0

```
<form method="POST" id="ovi" name="ovi" action="{{ route('booking.store') }}">
     @csrf
   // $BookingRequest->number_of_adults returns 3
  @for($i=1; $i<=$BookingRequest->number_of_adults; $i++)


<div class="col-sm-5 col-12">
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="first_name_{{$i}}" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" style="height:40px; font-size:0.9rem; border-radius:1px;" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name" >
   @error('first_name')
     <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
     </span>
 @enderror
 <div class="errormsg"></div>
</div>
</div>

 @endfor


//My JavaScript code

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("alpha", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{3,60}$/);
    });


    $("#ovi").validate({
        rules:{
            "first_name[]":{
                required: true,
                alpha   : true,
            }
        },
        messages:{
            "first_name[]":{
                required: "* first name is required",
                alpha   : "* Format is invalid",
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was in the name field indexing. I just added indexing in the name attribute and changed some jquery validation rules.

**Problem**

```
<input id="first_name_{{$i}}" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" style="height:40px; font-size:0.9rem; border-radius:1px;" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name" >
```

**Solved**

```
<input id="first_name{{$i}}" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" style="height:40px; font-size:0.9rem; border-radius:1px;" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name[{{$i}}]" placeholder="First Name" >
```

**Changing the validation rules FROM**

```
 $("#ovi").validate({
    rules:{
        "first_name[]":{
            required: true,
            alpha   : true,
        }
    },
    messages:{
        "first_name[]":{
            required: "* first name is required",
            alpha   : "* Format is invalid",
        }
    }
});
```

**TO**

```
$("#ovi").validate({
  ignore: false,
 });
  $('[id^=first_name]').each(function(e) {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            minlength: 2,
            required : true
        });
    });
```

> Hope this will save time to others as I spend three days to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the rules function with a loop, `alpha` rule doesn't exist use `lettersonly`

```js
$( "form" ).validate();
$('[id^=first_name_]').each(function(v,input) {
  $(input).rules('add', {
    required: true,
    lettersonly: true,
    messages: {
      required: "* first name is required",
      lettersonly: "* Format is invalid",
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="first_name_1}"  style="height:40px; font-size:0.9rem; border-radius:1px;" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name" >
<input id="first_name_2"  style="height:40px; font-size:0.9rem; border-radius:1px;" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name" >

<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

For all your error to trigger on submit you need uique names for each of your inputs

```js
$( "form" ).validate();
$('[id^=first_name_]').each(function(v,input) {
  $(input).rules('add', {
    required: true,
    lettersonly: true,
    messages: {
      required: "* first name is required",
      lettersonly: "* Format is invalid",
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="first_name_1}"  style="height:40px; font-size:0.9rem; border-radius:1px;" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name[1]" placeholder="First Name" >
<input id="first_name_2"  style="height:40px; font-size:0.9rem; border-radius:1px;" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name[2]" placeholder="First Name" >

<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried your solution but the results are same (only validating first input)

Comment: you are appending the new rows with jquery?

Comment: yes but I am appending it by PHP code. Using for loop

Comment: are you using javascript or php for the append?where is the append logic?does my update work?

Comment: I am using PHP to generate dynamic rows.

@for($i=1; $i<=$BookingRequest->number_of_adults; $i++)

// here is inputs

@endfor

No Your Code didn't work

Comment: any console errors?, did you call $( "form" ).validate() first?

Comment: No, not a single one. The solutions you are providing me didn't work in fact I tried all of them since morning. If I will delete the for loop, problem will be fixed but the thing is I need the for loop there. You see if you can help!

Yes i do call validate();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198654/discussion-between-owais-noor-and-madalinivascu).